# Error trying to use acro v3.5

Tags: packages, acronyms, acro

As soon as I use `acro` version 3.5 I get an error in the `acro.sty` file saying that

```
acro.sty (line 57)
Undefined control sequence. (\hook_gput_code:nnn ...)
```

My LaTeX code start as follows:

```latex
\documentclass[debug,nohyper,nobib]{tufte-book}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[hyperref=true]{acro}
\acsetup{list-style=longtable,list-short-format={\bfseries},only-used=false}
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is your latex up-to-date? hooks need latex 2020-10-01.

Comment: `acro.sty` was updated to use `lthooks` unconditionally, so that version doesn't work with older LaTeX (that is, you can't download it and install it manually).  Either update your distribution or use an older compatible `acro.sty`.

Comment: Thanks :) For some reason updating via tlmgr was retrieving me a message of success in updating latex, but then I installed TeXLive, updated there, and it worked just fine. Thank you very much to all of you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved by updating LaTeX